# Common causes of "'int' object has no attribute 'variable'"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Seeing as so many questions on Stack Overflow about the `'int' object has no attribute 'variable'` are too specific on only specific scenarios of such subject error message, I would like to know aspects of code I'd need to re-check in *any* given scenario involving such error message.

Simply speaking, there is not one question on this web that asks for a broad reasoning for said error message, and I would imagine quite a number of readers here would prefer these types of questions to be researched, as it is such a common occurrence that users here ask the same question but with questions and answers too specific to that specific area to be of any use. As a whole, many of the similar questions on this site are simply too specific to a specific context of someone's code.

I would like to make sure that this question is answered with an answer that would be answerable to almost any given situation regarding said error message. For such a commonly asked question, I would like most of the `'int' object has no attribute variable` issues to be addressed here.

Comment: The error _'foo' object has no attribute 'bar'_ means there is a bug in the program. There you go, an answer that applies to any such situation.

Comment: Your problem is that you are using a dynamically typed language. With a statically typed language you could not run the program with this bug in it. Perhaps you should look into type hinting for python to mitigate this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For such a commonly asked question, I would like most of the 'int'
>   object has no attribute variable issues to be addressed here.

Here goes my attempt.  First, this is not the best characterization:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'variable'
```

As most of the examples I see are of the form:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'method'
```

And were caused by calling a method on an `int` that isn't implemented by `int`:

```
>>> x = 4
>>> x.length()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'length'
>>>
```

The `int` class does have methods:

```
>>> dir(int)
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__bool__', '__ceil__', '__class__', '__delattr__',
'__dir__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__float__', '__floor__', '__floordiv__',
'__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__',
'__index__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__le__',
'__lshift__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__or__',
'__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__',
'__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ror__',
'__round__', '__rpow__', '__rrshift__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__',
'__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__',
'__truediv__', '__trunc__', '__xor__', 'bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator',
'from_bytes', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real', 'to_bytes']
>>>
```

and you can call them:

```
>>> help(int.bit_length)
Help on method_descriptor:

bit_length(...)
    int.bit_length() -> int

    Number of bits necessary to represent self in binary.
    >>> bin(37)
    '0b100101'
    >>> (37).bit_length()
    6

>>>
```

Which shows us how to invoke a method on an `int` without the period being confused with a decimal point:

```
>>> (128).bit_length()
8
>>>
```

But the majority of the time, it's not that someone's trying to call a method on an `int` but rather that an `int` is the mistaken recipient of a message meant for another object type. For example, this is a common error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Which arises in Python2 when you try to subscript an `int`:

```
>>> x = 4
>>> x[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
>>>
```

Python3 gives the more helpful message, `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`.

This can sometimes happen if you reuse the same variable name to hold different types of data -- a practice to be avoided.

If you get an error like `"AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'"`, think about what type of object responds to `append()`.  A `list` does, so somewhere in my code I call `append()` on an `int` where I thought I had a `list`.

Comment: Ah, I must've not known that it's `'int' object has no attribute 'method'` and not `'int' object has no attribute 'variable'`. I now understand the causes of the error.

Comment: @RonZhang, technically, it could be an instance variable, but the examples I found in my search mostly turned out to be methods so I focused on that.